# Getting problem in fixing the error ResolvePackageNotFound:

Tags: python, anaconda, algorithmic-trading

I've been trying to create a conda environment by `conda env create -f environment.yml` but getting an error like:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - wheel==0.29.0=py36_0
  - pandas-datareader==0.4.0=py36_0
  - tk==8.5.18=vc14_0
  - requests==2.14.2=py36_0
  - pandas==0.20.3=py36_0
  - jpeg==9b=vc14_0
  - requests-ftp==0.3.1=py36_0
  - qt==5.6.2=vc14_6
  - icu==57.1=vc14_0
  - zlib==1.2.8=vc14_3
  - requests-file==1.4.1=py36_0
  - statsmodels==0.8.0=np113py36_0
  - python-dateutil==2.6.1=py36_0
  - scipy==0.19.1=np113py36_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py36_1
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py36_1
  - six==1.10.0=py36_0
  - numpy==1.13.1=py36_0
  - openssl==1.0.2l=vc14_0
  - mkl==2017.0.3=0
  - pytz==2017.2=py36_0
  - matplotlib==2.0.2=np113py36_0
  - patsy==0.4.1=py36_0
  - python==3.6.2=0
  - cycler==0.10.0=py36_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py36_2
  - libpng==1.6.27=vc14_0
  - pyparsing==2.1.4=py36_0
  - sip==4.18=py36_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.0.25420=0
```

After looking through some of the solutions online i put all the packages(as in dependencies) not installed in `-pip:` and again getting an error as shown:

```
Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.  Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.  I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['C:\\Users\\vandi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\pyfinance\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', 'C:\\Stock\\Notebooks\\condaenv.fl4e_z75.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:

Pip subprocess error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'cycler=0.10.0=py36_0' (from line 8 of C:\Stock\Notebooks\condaenv.fl4e_z75.requirements.txt)
Hint: = is not a valid operator. Did you mean == ?


CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

Please help me out in fixing this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install cycler==0.10.0, then execute the command below,

pip install cycler==0.10.0